# Google Analytics Cross Domain Tracking Conversion Referral Issue

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, referrals

So I have two sites for a client, we'll say **www.main.com** is their main website and **www.signup.com** is a site where the user signs up for a certain service.

I recently switched **signup.com** over to universal analytics so that we could implement cross-domain tracking via the autolink plugin.

I used [this article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en) to help me set up the code on each domain.

Here is what I have on **main.com**:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-11865301-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['signup.com'] );

  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

*NOTE: I'm not sure what 'displayfeatures' is. I was told that a 3rd party vendor had to customize the code at one point and that I shouldn't remove anything.*

And here is what I have on **signup.com**:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-11865301-1', 'auto'), {'allowLinker': true};
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['main.com'] );
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I also have both domains listed in my Referral Exclusion List so that we don't see **main.com** as referrals for the signup goal.

What's happening now though, is that for almost all of our conversions, the source/medium is showing as (direct)/(none) and the referral path is showing as (not set). We cannot figure out why.

At the time of this posting there are 14 goal conversions for the day. All of them are reporting a referral path of (not set) and 13 of them are reporting a source/medium of (direct)/(none). There is one conversion that has it's source/medium listed as bing/organic, if that is any kind of clue.

I'm not finding a lot of results on the subject in my googling so this is my last resort. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** So I've been researching this heavily for the past 24 hours and have found out more information.

The (direct) or (not set) referral sources are coming from **main.com**. The reason they are listed as direct or not set referrals is because we have **main.com** listed in the referral exclusion list. When I turned it off these referrals started coming is as **main.com**.

It's starting to look more and more like there is no way to take the original referrer from **main.com** and carry it over to **signup.com**.

Can anyone confirm or deny this theory?

Comment: "displayfeatures" is used for demographics, interests reporting, and remarketing. It should have no bearing on your conversions and cross-domain tracking though.

Comment: @nyuen Yea I kind of figured it wasn't part of the problem. I just wanted to state ahead of time in case someone asked that I didn't put that in there and I didn't really know what it was. But thanks for the knowledge, now I know.

Comment: I understand this is possible if use the same analytics ID for both sites.

Answer (score 0):

When you link domains for cross-domain tracking, they should all be included in the autoLink.

```
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['signup.com', 'main.com'] );
```

Comment: That's not what the documentation says.